# Could not locate PropertySource because of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, microservices

I created a docker image and pushed it to docker hub. Now, I am trying to run it on a remote machine by using `docker-compose` and I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:132)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:93)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:567)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:338)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
my-test_1  |    at net.ptidej.seodin.SeodinApp.main(SeodinApp.java:68)
my-test_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
my-test_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
my-test_1  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
my-test_1  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
my-test_1  | Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/seodin/prod/master": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:674)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:539)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:172)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:93)
my-test_1  |    ... 13 common frames omitted
my-test_1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
my-test_1  |    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
my-test_1  |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
my-test_1  |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
my-test_1  |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
my-test_1  |    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
my-test_1  |    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
my-test_1  |    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
my-test_1  |    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
my-test_1  |    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
my-test_1  |    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
my-test_1  |    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
my-test_1  |    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
my-test_1  |    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
my-test_1  |    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
my-test_1  |    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
my-test_1  |    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
my-test_1  |    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:112)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$GenericRequestHeaderInterceptor.intercept(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:237)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:88)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:72)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
my-test_1  |    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:660)
my-test_1  |    ... 17 common frames omitted
my-test_1  |
```

I am guessing it has something to do with ports in one of the config files, but I don't know which one. What is the meaning of this error and where should I look to resolve it? I would appreciate any lead/hint to the problem in the source code/config files. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring Boot app is configured to load properties from a Spring Cloud Config server specified at

http://localhost:8761/config/seodin/prod/master

and it can't see it.

As you are running in Docker either make sure that a config server is running in Docker as well, and that your Spring Boot app is configured to point at that (the URL will not be localhost; it's likely to be the container name of the config server ifyou are running that in Docker, or the URL of an external config server)

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside of a `Docker` container, `localhost` resolves to that container not `Docker Host`. So you should change the IP address of the `Config Server` to `Docker Host` IP address or your LAN IP address in your application configurations. Of course it will work if you have a running `Config Server` in your machine.

Comment: Where can I find the Config Server IP defined to change it to Docker Host?

Comment: it can be `spring.cloud.config.uri` config in your application.properties or bootstrap.properties file. take a look at [this link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/), it might be helpful.

Comment: Also there is another strange thing in your question. Port 8761 is standard port for `Eureka Discovery Server` and port 8888 is standard port for `Configuration Server`. But your logs shows that your app is trying to fetch it's configurations from `Configuration Server` at port 8761.